# Using facebook sdk in AWS lambda?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, lambda, aws-lambda

Is it possible to use facebook sdk(js) in aws lambda? I need to use facebook graph api to fetch content, it's working on browser but i need to move it to aws.